# Dog stepped on finish before it was dry. How should I go about fixing this?

Tags: wood, flooring, finish

My dog stepped on my new floor.   Left paw prints in the finish. What are your suggestions for fixing it?

I plan to sand it down and was going to use a high grit sand paper.

Then reapply a new finish.  **The issue is I don't know what finish the company used** and I wont be able to get ahold of them again.  Any suggestions?  What happens if I apply a different finish?  Will it mess up the floor more?

Thanks.

Comment: Step one, wash the dog's feet very well before it licks the finish off its feet and gets sick.

Comment: You will want to use the same finish. Sanding slightly beyond (deeper) what is obvious and a larger area will help blend the repair. The sooner you complete the repair the better chance to get similar results (without the paw prints). Call the company that did the work if they have part of the can left they may give you a good price and having the same batch helps match but not a guarantee.